# Extending Dual Monitors with VGA and HDMI to Single link DVI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, vga

Here is my question. I have a workstation running windows 7 on a Dell Optiplex 390. He would like to use two extended monitors. The graphics card is an Intel Graphics HD 2000. It has a VGA out and HDMI out. I want to convert the HDMI to Single Link DVI then extend the screens using the VGA/DVI. Is this possible or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Might be cheaper to get a new graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with an HDMI -> DVI-D (*DIGITAL*) adapter, but have a look at this from the Intel website:

> What are the system requirements for Multiple Display support? Your
> computer must have the following:
>
> Physical video output connector(s)
>
> Your computer must have a video
> output connector or connectors to which one or more external displays
> would be connected to. Some laptops may have additional video output
> connectors on a docking station, port replicator, or via the laptop
> manufacturer’s special video cable. On desktop systems, some computer
> manufacturers may offer at an extra cost an add-in card (referred to
> as ADD2) which adds video output connector to the computer.
>
> Two or more display devices are connected.
>
> Display devices may include an
> analog monitor, notebook’s built-in display, external monitor or flat
> panel display with analog, DVI-D, DVI-I, HDMI*, or DisplayPort*
> connectors, or television with S-Video, Composite, Component, or D
> connectors. Not all display device combinations may be supported by
> your computer. Please check with your computer manufacturer for
> information on the supported multiple display configurations for your
> computer.
>
> An Intel® graphics driver is installed.
>
> The Intel graphics
> driver’s Properties control panel allows you to set a multiple display
> configuration. Not all multiple display configurations may be
> supported by your operating system or by your computer. Some examples
> include: The Starter Editions of Windows Vista* & Windows 7* do not
> support Extended Desktop mode; Many computer manufacturers disable the
> Twin mode. Please check with your computer manufacturer for
> information on available and supported multiple display configurations
> for your computer.

http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-031040.htm

***UPDATE:

I might be wrong.  Look at this, and check all the comments.  It appears people have mixed results.  I've seen multiple outputs work on many Optiplex models so it might still be possible to do it if you have the right drivers:

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3515/t/19410045.aspx

> Before Connecting Mutiple Monitors or a Monitor and a Television to
> Your Computer
>
> To support dual monitors or a monitor and a television, you must have
> an optional graphics card. If you are connecting more than one
> monitor, ensure that the connectors on your monitors (whether VGA or
> DVI) match the available connectors on your computer, or that you have
> any necessary adapters. For example, if you have a VGA monitor that
> needs to be connected to a DVI port on your graphics card, you must
> have the optional DVI adapter.

Comment: I have read that second forum and deduced that I could try out the fixes they suggest, however it still doesn't clarify whether or not those fixes make it so the screens can be extended ( I know my version of 7 pro supports it.) so the only thing I am apprehensive about is that it will still only be a clone and not an extension. Also thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: `To support dual monitors` .. `you must have an optional graphics card.`. I read this as: If you add another card which supports this then you can do it. And since you already need an extra card you might as well connect all three screens (primary and two two extended displays) to it and use a single driver.

Comment: I understand what your saying however it is already shown you can run the dual monitors with the integrated hd 2000. However my issue is if the screens can be extended. I already know it will clone off of a HDMI to Single Link DVI with another VGA. I just want to extend two screens that's it. Thanks for your input though it is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You would unfortunately be wasting your time. Although you would be trying to use an HDMI->DVI adapter out of the video card, the input is still recognized on your PC as being HDMI, so you still wouldn't be able to to so since you are still technically using two different forms of output.

You would be better off upgrading to a new card if you can.

Comment: I have used a HDMI to DVI and VGA dual monitor setup in the past.  You don't indicate why that combination is not possible.

Comment: Because it cannot span across two different outputs/output signals. If it was VGA/DVI yes. HDMI/DVI no.

Comment: I should have asked you this first, are you just extending your desktop, or trying to do this with something like eyefinity and span it?

Comment: I personally have used a HDMI to DVI cable along with a VGA cable to another monitor so your statment is not entirely accurate.  I doubt the author will answer your follow-up question he hasn't be around for a year.

Comment: Haha, I figured the same thing. didn't notice the date of the question until a while after posting. I have used the same also and have a similar setup now, extending the desktop is no problem. I assumed he was trying to span as you would for gaming. My mistake, thanks for the downvote, lulllllllllll

Comment: I don't find the answer vey helpful thus the downvote.  As for correctable specifics....The inaccurate information and simply saying to replace the graphics card ( the user isn't even using one based on his own description ) is a start.

Comment: Yes, on board, can see.